# get agent methods by using this.myagent in a Behaviour

Tags: agents-jade

I have one agent with its services that implements a `CyclicBehaviour` were and I wanna see those services or use its methods, how can I do it?

for example

Agent:

```
public class agent1 extends Agent {

int[] numbers= {11, 20, 40};
public void setup() {
    DFAgentDescription dfd = new DFAgentDescription();
    dfd.setName(getAID());
    ServiceDescription sd = new ServiceDescription();
    sd.setName("number");
    sd.setType(numbers[0]);
    sd.addOntologies("ontology");
    ..........
    sd.addNumbers(new SLCodec().getName());
    dfd.addServices(sd);

    try {
        DFService.register(this, dfd);
    }
    catch(FIPAException e) {
        System.err.println("Agente"+ getLocalName()+": "+ e.getMessage());
    }
};

public String getNumber()
{
    return idiomas;
}
```

}

Behaviour:

```
public class CyclicTraduce extends CyclicBehaviour {
 @Override
public void action() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //I want to use getNumber method of agent here
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the behaviour is used by agent1 then just use casting (without registering services)

`((agent1) myAgent).getNumber()`

otherwise you have to look for the registered services:

```
DFAgentDescription template = new DFAgentDescription();
ServiceDescription sd = new ServiceDescription();
sd.setType("type to be searched");
template.addServices(sd);

DFAgentDescription[] result = DFService.search(myAgent,template);
result[0].getName() // aid to send to in order to invoke the method
```

and send a message for agent1 that will invoke `getNumber` and reply with a result.